# Need to call the client twice before the message the server received is printed

Tags: c, sockets, server, udp

I am working on a project that requires the implementation of a server-client. I send a message over a UDP socket that has been put together using sprintf() (to account for integer conversions to strings). When I write the message to the server, the first time nothing happens, but then when I write to the server the second time, the server prints out both the original message and the second message at once. I feel I may be misusing the sprintf function but I'm not sure.
Here are the important parts of the code:

```
int server_write(int num1, int num2, char *buffer){
    char fullmessage[1000];
    sprintf(fullmessage, "%d %d %s ", num1, num2, buffer);
    UDP_Write(sd, addr, fullmessage, strlen(fullmessage)); 
}
```

sd and addr are global vars and UDP_Write is a helper function that is assumed to work (which I verified). Then the server code

```
int main(void){
     while(1){
          struct sockaddr_in addrRec;
          char message[50];
          int rc = UDP_Read(sd, addrRec, message, 50);
          if(rc > 0){
               printf("%s\n", message);
          }
     }
}
```

There is more to it but these are the parts that are important and do not work properly. I feel it has more to do with the use of sprintf() and isn't really a UDP problem because I can get the messages sent eventually so that shows the UDP programming works and the client receives the confirmation message that the server sends (not shown).

Comment: The client sends the message without a NUL terminator `'\0'`. So before printing the message on the server side, you should add the terminator, e.g. `message[rc] = '\0';` Of course, the buffer needs room for the terminator, so either make the buffer bigger `char message[51]` or pass 49 to the `UDP_Read` function.

Comment: The use of `addrRec` seems odd. If that parameter is an input to the function, you need code to fill it with the client's address. If it's an output from the function, then you should be passing the address of the structure: `UDP_Read(sd, &addrRec, message, 50);`

Comment: What is the function prototype for the `UDP_Read` function?

Comment: @user3386109 the null terminator was the problem. To answer the other questions, the addrRec gets filled by UDP_Read, it stores the information of the client who sent the processed request so that addrReq can be used to send a response to the sender. That is why it gets passed in uninited.

Comment: No null terminator is needed in this example. Use the return values of `sprintf()` and `UDP_Read()`, eg: `int len = sprintf(...); UDP_Write(..., len);` ... `int rc = UDP_Read(...); ... printf("%.*s\n", rc, message);` Just be aware that 1) `server_write()` has a potential buffer overflow if `buffer` is larger than `fullmessage` can hold, and 2) `main()` is using a very small buffer compared to what `server_write()` is using to format the string, so there is potential for data truncation on the receiving end.

Comment: The udp protocol doesn't help you where the tcp does, so when you send data you should send their size as well, then while receiving you should read, first the size and then the data sent for the received size., no more no less.